# i can't inject script to a site with content.js chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, extension-methods

i am trying to inject script to a site with **chrome extension manifest v3** to do someworks with site's window object,like disable alert or sniff xmlHttpRequests and listens to them and their response.
so when i'm using this code in **Content.js :**

> **Content.js :**

```
const alertScript = document.createElement('script');
alertScript.innerHTML = `window.alert=function(){console.log('alert disabled!')};`
document.head.appendChild(alertScript);
```

But it didn't work and this error was in console :

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security
 Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword,
 a hash ('sha256-UVElatCQi2odTlw3V21Lr91ia1hU68fiNgVYG5EZibk='),
a nonce is required to enable inline execution.
```

p.s : In manifest v2 , i don't have this problem and easily can inject scripts without any error.But in manifest v3 i have this problem.

Am i need a permission or do something ??

thanks for your help ..

Answer (score 1):

[MV3 imposes new restrictions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#code-execution) that limit an extension's ability to execute unreviewed JavaScript through a combination of platform changes and policy limitations.

An `'unsafe-inline'` token is ignored in manifest v3, so there is no way to execute inline scripts.
Don't use inline scripts, you can do exactly the same in a separate file.